# End Date minus Start Date calculation with a criteria

Tags: validation-rule

I need to put a validation rule where if ,
(End date - Start date ) > 12 months + 30 days, It should throw the validation error.
Now , for months I can use as per below , but I couldnt able to figure out how to add the plus 30 days in it.

```
MONTH(End_Date__c)-MONTH(Start_date__c)>12
```

Comment: 30 days is exactly 1 month. So why don't you use `> 13`

Comment: For Adding 30 days, append your formula with this: `+ DAY(DATE( YEAR( TODAY() ), 1, 30))`

Comment: Hi Reshma, I have not used that as I want to take leap year as well. Its a config for finance dept, so 1 day difference also need to be calculated. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to use `(End_Date__c - Start_date__c) > (365 + 30)` if you don't care much of a leap year one day difference, exact validation for 12 month (which is 1 year) + 30 days would look like

`End_Date__c > (DATE( YEAR(Start_date__c) + 1, MONTH(Start_date__c), DAY(Start_date__c)) + 30)`

**UPDATE:** I just tested and the above formula is failing on Feb 29 calculations, and I think that **`(End_Date__c - Start_date__c) > (365 + 30)`** is perfect.

You can find an example by searching by the sting ["Adding Days, Months, and Years to a Date" *here*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm)

Comment: Hello Oleksiy, thanks you. What if we want to take the leap year as well ? whaat change I want to make here plz ?

Comment: see my edit, well just update...